# Преобразование элементов списка из str в int python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, статистика

Есть CSV файл:

```
2014-03-01,47
2014-03-02,33
2014-03-03,39
2014-03-04,33
2014-03-05,46
2014-03-06,44
2014-03-07,38
2014-03-08,35
2014-03-09,39
2014-03-10,36
2014-03-11,35
```

я взял `int` значение, и построил список, который пытаюсь прокорелировать (определить коэффициент Пирсона) с графиком, который строю из функции (экспоненциально нарастающей синусоиды):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy

(pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Chechire Cat\Downloads\multiTimeline.csv', header=None, names=['dt', 'val'], parse_dates=['dt'], dtype={'val': 'float'}, skiprows=3)[['val']].to_csv(r'C:\Users\Chechire Cat\PycharmProjects\mosia\vallls.csv', index=False,     header=None, date_format='%d.%m.%Y'))

file = open(r'C:\Users\Chechire Cat\PycharmProjects\mosia\vallls.csv', 'r+')
f = file.read()

t = np.arange(0.6, 9.9, 0.1)
list2 = ((1 - np.exp(-t)) * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))

f1 = f.split('\n')
list1 = [float(x) for x in f1]

print(list1)
```

Почему не выходить? Почему я не могу нормально перевести из `str` в `int`? Пробелов вроде нету, но оно мне говорит:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите в вопрос (кнопка `править`) стек трассы с ошибкой, а то непонятно в какой строке произошла ошибка. А так, у вас ошибка говорит что в `int` попала пустая строка, вот сами попробуйте: `int('')`

Comment: Добавил картинку в вопрос

Comment: Лучше, но картинка и код вещи почти не совместимые, лучше вместо картинки скопируйте красный текст в консоли и вставьте в вопрос, так вы очень поможете другим участникам сайта в помощи вам :)

Comment: Кст, код в вопросе отличается от вашего кода на скриншоте. Не надо так :) Насчет вашей проблемы сделайте так: `list1 = [int(x) for x in f1 if x]` или `list1 = [int(x) for x in f1 if x.isdecimal()]`

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы прочитать CSV файл в Pandas DataFrame можно воспользоваться [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

Пример CSV файла с пустой строкой:

```
#  строки 
#  которые надо
#  пропустить ...
2014-03-01,47
2014-03-02,33
2014-03-03,39
2014-03-04,33
2014-03-05,46

2014-03-06,44
2014-03-07,38
2014-03-08,35
2014-03-09,39
2014-03-10,36
2014-03-11,35
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Chechire Cat\Downloads\multiTimeline.csv', 
                 header=None, names=['dt', 'val'], 
                 parse_dates=['dt'], dtype={'val': 'float'},
                 skiprows=3)
```

DataFrame:

```
In [247]: df
Out[247]:
           dt   val
0  2014-03-01  47.0
1  2014-03-02  33.0
2  2014-03-03  39.0
3  2014-03-04  33.0
4  2014-03-05  46.0
5  2014-03-06  44.0
6  2014-03-07  38.0
7  2014-03-08  35.0
8  2014-03-09  39.0
9  2014-03-10  36.0
10 2014-03-11  35.0
```

Столбец Pandas DataFrame (Series) можно легко представить в виде Numpy array:

```
In [248]: df['val'].values
Out[248]: array([47., 33., 39., 33., 46., 44., 38., 35., 39., 36., 35.])
```

или в виде "Vanilla Python" списка:

```
In [249]: df['val'].values.tolist()
Out[249]: [47.0, 33.0, 39.0, 33.0, 46.0, 44.0, 38.0, 35.0, 39.0, 36.0, 35.0]
```